# Git branch no tracking information

Tags: git

After git pull I get this output.

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> my_branch
```

Problem is that I have created that branch and have done tones of commits on this branch and switching to other branches and getting back to this one. Than a new user added few commits and after that I am getting this message.

My question is **not how to fix this I want to know what cause this** and how to prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you didn't set the `upstream` (which means which remote branch you want to track).

**To set the tracking remote branch:**

If the local branch is created in your local machine, then when you push to the remote, you could use `-u`/`--set-upstream` option when you do `git push`.

If the branch is checked out from a remote branch, then you could use `--track` option when you do `git checkout`.

**To fix this(set a remote tracking branch), just do what git tell you:**

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> my_branch
```

Comment: So by default I only have upstream to master branch, and every other branch that other people commits to I have to set upstream?

Comment: @1392023093user One branch could only have one upstream, if you don't set there will no upstream. `master` branch's upstream is set when you did clone the project.

Comment: I'm confused about the / in origin/<branch>. I'm also confused about what <branch> is supposed to be. I'm also confused about why I need to do this. Thanks for the magic answer keeping me confused.