# Rebase a series of branches into parallel Branches

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase

I frequently end up with a series of branches built one from the other like this:

```
...-(M)
     |
     +-A
       |
       +-B
         |
         +-C
```

Usually with pull-requests for each of A, B and C.

The issue is that if I request a Pull request from C it includes all the changes made in the branches A and B, which just irritates people.

I would like to re-structure the graph such that it looks like:

```
...-(M)
     |
     +-A
     |
     +-B
     |
     +-C
```

But each time I attempt to rebase either 'B' or 'C' onto '(M)' the structure remains the same.

What would be the correct way to restructure this?

By the way, I use SourceTree for all my Git-related needs but am happy to translate from console instructions if necessary.

Edit: The solution suggested by VonC did indeed work however it would not work for me while I was using SourceTree's builtin version of Git.  After downloading a portable version from here: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.14.2.windows.3 it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any rebase which does not involve *all* the previous commits is a `rebase --onto` command.

```
git checkout C
git rebase --onto M B C
```

That means: rebase everything *after* B (B excluded) up to C (C included) onto M.

```
git checkout B
git rebase --onto M A B
```

Note: for that, it is best to use the `git bash` of the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [`PortableGit-2.14.2.3-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.2.windows.3/PortableGit-2.14.2.3-64-bit.7z.exe) unzipped anywhere you want). That will avoid weird bugs like "There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to rebase against." that [I mentionned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37875545/6309).
A `rebase` is a local operation, and should not be concerned with remote branches.

Comment: Thank you VonC.  I have been trying very similar to that while following this post: https://makandracards.com/makandra/10173-git-how-to-rebase-your-feature-branch-from-one-branch-to-another

However both the linked example (with 2 arguments) and your example (with three arguments) give the error message: "There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to rebase against." and I am struggling to understand what that means.

Comment: @Slartibartfast Strange, this should involve local branches: no remote tracking branch is needed. But if you must: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729663/6309

Comment: @Slartibartfast By the way, which Git version are you using, on which OS? And does git branch -v display A, B and C?

Comment: I'm using SourceTree's builtin version of Git (version 2.12.2.windows.2) on Windows 10.  The 'master' branch I'm attempting to rebase onto is local but 'Upstream/master' is at the same point as well.

Comment: And yes, 'A', 'B' and 'C' are all displayed when I type "git branch -v" (as is 'M' - 'master').  Branch 'C' is coloured green, I assume to indicate that it's checkedout. I also used tab-completion to enter the branch names and each branch tab-completes properly.

Comment: Oh, something I just realised might be relevant is that while branches 'B' and 'C' have been 'committed' I have not yet 'pushed' them to 'origin' as I wanted to sought this issue out before pushing.

Comment: Don't matter,the rebase is purely a local operation. Don't rebase master. Rebase c, then b, as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156797/discussion-between-slartibartfast-and-vonc).